# MySQL Max and Correspondace record Values

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my table structure and record for table_1

```
| id | user_id | salary |    date    |
| 1  |    1    |  1100  | 2015-01-16 |
| 2  |    1    |  2100  | 2015-01-17 |
| 3  |    1    |  2200  | 2015-01-18 |
| 4  |    1    |  2100  | 2015-01-19 |

| 5  |    2    |  2000  | 2015-01-20 |
| 6  |    2    |  3000  | 2015-01-17 |
| 7  |    2    |  7000  | 2015-01-18 |
| 8  |    2    |  6000  | 2015-01-19 |
| 9  |    2    |  2000  | 2015-01-21 |
```

And i am executing following query to get the max, sum and its correspondence date for the records.

```
select max(salary) , sum(salary),date, user_id from table_1 where year(health.hlt_date) = year(now()) and week(health.hlt_date) = week(now()) group by user_id
```

Output is following

```
 user_id | max(salary) | sum(salary) |    date    
   1    |  2200       |  7500       | 2015-01-19 |
   2    |  7000       |  20000      | 2015-01-17 |
   3    |  9000       |  9000       | 2015-01-16 |
```

max and sum are fetched correctly but dates are not correct , i want the dates for the max salary like for user 1, i want date '2015-01-18'.

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Thanks god in mysql 5.7 `only full group by` will be the default.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there are more appropriate ways to do this, but this is all I could think of now. Bring the aggregate data from the table_1 and once you get the record having max(salary) and corresponding user_id, join it with itself to find the date of that id and salary. Not very efficient but try something like this:

```
select A.*, B.date
(select max(salary) salary , sum(salary) totSal, user_id from table_1 where year(health.hlt_date) = year(now()) and week(health.hlt_date) = week(now()) group by user_id) A
inner join
(select date, user_id, salary from table_1) B
on
A.user_id = B.user_id
and
A.salary = B.salary
```

or may be something like this :

```
select user_Id, MaxSal, totSal, date
(select max(salary) MaxSal, salary, sum(salary) totSal, user_id, date from table_1 where year(health.hlt_date) = year(now()) and week(health.hlt_date) = week(now()) group by user_id, date) A
where salary = MaxSal
```

Comment: Will it also work , if i want to get he same out put for more than one column in same table like salary, compensation, extra_hour_payment etc. i want to have all the columns  max and sum with their correspondence date.

Comment: ideally it should, provided you give proper mapping of columns in the join. Plus, one can't say much without looking at your model, as one row might contain max sal, with date and other might contain max compensation, so it will differ what date you plan to show

Comment: Exactly, i have same situation, different columns have different max dates.  but i want all the max record dates. What you suggest ?

Comment: I'm afraid it won't work, a subquery within the select clause must return only one column and one value.

Comment: @Gervs, forgot the "from" keyword, small typo, will rectify it :) thnx for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create a subset of data:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|  user_id  |  max_sal  |
+-----------+-----------+
|     1     |    2200   |
+-----------+-----------+
|     2     |    7000   |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Then you join the same table again with both columns in the join condition, the query looks like:

```
SELECT
    d.user_id,
    m.max_sal,
    d.date date_max_sal,
    (SELECT SUM(h.salary) FROM table_1 h
    WHERE h.user_id = d.user_id /* AND THE OTHER CONDITIONS */) sum_sal
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        MAX(salary) max_sal
    FROM
        table_1
    /* WHERE clause */
    GROUP BY user_id
    ) m
    JOIN
        table_1 d
        ON m.user_id = d.user_id AND m.max_sal = d.salary
    /* WHERE clause */
```

I've taken into account that the max value may occur twice, so I used a correlated subquery in the sum.
If you want results from a certain period (it looks like that but you're referring to tables which are not in the FROM so I left that out) replace the comments with the WHERE conditions